Victoria Metrics agent scrapping from AWS ECS with Fargate
I'm configuring a VM Agent on AWS ECS Fargate and would like to scrap a bunch of services running on AWS ECS Fargate too (same cluster), but I didn't find any ECS automatic discovery right here: https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs/.
So, I can use this one dns_sd_configs (https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs/#dns_sd_configs) pointing to my AWS CloudMap and it resolves all IPs under my AWS ECS task.
But I wonder if it's the better approach. Another approach would be to add my VM agent as sidecar on each AWS ECS Task.
Any tips here folks?

The question was answered in VictoriaMetrics' Slack, so I'll duplicate the answer here:
for now, vmagent only support ec2_sd_configs like prometheus does. One reason for not having ECS SD:
Some SD mechanisms have rate limits that make them challenging to use. As an example we have unfortunately had to reject Amazon ECS service discovery due to the rate limits being so low that it would not be usable for anything beyond small setups. 
But there is an open proposal in prometheus which looks possible, feel free to create a feature request to https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics.
